# Webpack worker-loader silently fails on errors

Tags: javascript, webpack, worker-loader

I'm using CRA to configure my projects, then eject and add whatever else I need. In this case I simply added worker-loader to module rules:

```
    {
      test: /\.worker\.js$/,
      loader: 'worker-loader'
    },
```

The problem is that if there are compilation errors in worker code, it still reports production build as successful, but the output folder only has a handful of files (development builds work fine). The only way to get error messages is to rename the worker script so it's imported as a regular module.

How do I get it to properly report errors?

Webpack 4.29.6, worker-loader 2.0.0.

If it matters, the errors come from eslint, which isn't aware of some worker-specific globals and requires comments to disable errors for specific lines.

Comment: What does your full webpack config look like?

Comment: Stock config from (almost) latest version of CRA, with worker-loader for `.worker.js` as mentioned seems to be enough to reproduce it. Here's my current config which also uses exports-loader for .jscc and overrides defaultRules so webassembly doesn't break, but that doesn't affect the issue from what I remember.

Comment: In your webpack file, can you add `optimization: {
    noEmitOnErrors: false, ...` and see if you get any errors?

Comment: `If it matters, the errors come from eslint, which isn't aware of some worker-specific globals and requires comments to disable errors for specific lines.`
This was my issue, Had to fix the eslint errors and it worked after that